# Angles at points of Intersection between a line and a sphere

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

I am doing a supervised study course on Multivariate Calculus! I have this question from the textbook that I don't really understand.

Calculate the angle between the line $(6; 8; 5) + t (3; 4; 5);$ t 2 R and the sphere
$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 25$ at their points of intersection.

My attempt:
- I expressed the line equation in parametric form and plug them into the equation of sphere. Then I found out the t_0 and t_1. Plug them back into the parametric equation respectively, I would get the two points of intersection.
- Then I assumed "normal to the surface" is congruent to the concept of "normal of the tangent plane to the surface at a specific point", so I took the gradient of the sphere equation and plug into the (x0,y0,z0) and (x1,y1,z1) to find the normal.

My question is now...how do I find the angle between the two lines. I haven't learned anything about parametrization yet so I assume this question would not need any parameterization? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

hint: recall that $\langle x,y\rangle = ||x||\cdot ||y||\cos\theta$ where $\theta=\angle(x,y)$ is the angle between the vectors $x$ and $y$